# Fine vs Coarse grained crypto API

Tags: api, cryptography

Is there any good reason for picking a coarse api over a fine grained one especially for crypto processing?

Coarse:

```
AESDecrypt(pad_type,
           mode_type, 
           mode_data, /* CTR or IV */
           ciphertext,
           plaintext)
```

Fine:

```
AES128_ECB_Decrypt(ciphertext, plaintext)
AES128_CBC_PKCS5_Decrypt(iv, ciphertext, plaintext)
AES128_CBC_NOPAD_Decrypt(iv, ciphertext, plaintext)
AES256_CTR_Decrypt(ctr, ciphertext, plaintext)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not really any difference in functionality (or security).

With the *only one function for all* version, you can change the algorithm and mode without recompiling (if your application takes these values from somewhere else), and the library can support new algorithms without API changes.

In the *lots of different functions* version your application either is locked to a particular algorithm or you need a lot of if/case statements to support multiple ones.

Comment: How skilled in cryptography are you users likely to be?  Giving unskilled users too many choices is a bad thing in crypto - they will make mistakes.  By restricting choices, such as not offering ECB mode, you can help users avoid errors.

Comment: This is a good point, but a bit orthogonal to the question. It also only applies to people creating their own protocols, not ones implementing existing ones. Having a good documentation which warns about specific choices (either of functions or of parameters) could help here.

Comment: Skillz are not really a worry. We are abstracting our libraries crypto calls to allow a porter add their own custom library. We wonder are there adv's or disadv's of either interface for such a porter.